# jquery making changes to a dynamic div

Tags: jquery, html

Morning everyone, can anyone help with the following please. I have some basic `HTML` code a table within a `div`, and I want to change the `background colour` as the mouse moves over rows. I have this working fine with the code I have enclosed. However if the content within the `div` is dynamic and changes/loaded after the page has been run, I am unable to change the `background colour`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "red"
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
 tr:hover
 {
    background-color:red;
 }
</style>
```

And if you want to make the transition smoother, you can use :

```
tr {    
  -webkit-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, if you already have specific background colour on a cell in the row being hovered, then this answer will not override that colour. If you wanted to, you could do it this way: `tr:hover td { background-color:red; }`

Comment: i dont think so. i have done it many times. it replaces the current color.

Comment: Here you can see @ShahiM - table 1 is your solution, table 2 is mine. http://jsfiddle.net/17d592bd/

Comment: @wf4. sorry. I earlier did not get what you were saying. Now I do. thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the same as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").on("hover", function() {
        $(this).css({ "background-color","red"});
    })
});
```

This will surely help if you have used correct selector.
Also you can do it as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">
 selector:hover
 {
    background-color:red;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Using CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#divId tr:hover
 {
    background-color:red;
 }
</style>
```

**Using Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).attr("style","background-color:red");
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use css

```
<style type="text/css">
 tr:hover
 {
    background-color:red;
 }
</style>
```

If you really want to use jQuery, then add that property after creating and appending the row.

like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $("#table"); //select the table.let its id 'table'
    var tr = $("<tr>"); // creating row
    $(table).append(tr); // appending
    $(tr).mouseover(function() { // applying style
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "red"
        });
    })
});
```